# Import a module which moved to another folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to include a module, which has been moved to another folder without changing the import statement. How can I do an import mapping to point to the new location?

Here is the original folder structure:

- Root

  - main.py
  - folder_1

    - X.py
  - folder_2

    - Y.py
  - folder_3

In main.py:

```py
# I'm using reflection to find and import X.py runtime
__import__(folder1.X)
```

In X.py:

```py
import folder_2.Y as Y
def X_func():
   print(Y.somefunc())
```

In Y.py:

```py
def somefunc():
   print('I feel good')
```

Now, Y.py is located under folder_3 and the include does not work. Is it possible to re-map the include statements somehow to point to the new folder?

I tried with setuptools, but I dont want to create a distribution

```py
setuptools.setup(
        entry_points={
            '????': [
                'somefunc = folder_2.Y:somefunc',
            ],
        },
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in `X.py`:-

```
import folder_3.Y as Y
def X_func():
   print(Y.somefunc())
```

If this does not work, then try using:-

```
import sys
sys.path.append('full_path_to_the_third_folder')

import Y as Y
```